# Rescue of a live system after deleting LVM signature when recreating partition of new size

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, vmware

I have done something stupid, I'll admit right away. Thankfully, it was done on a test system.

I have a DNS server running in a virtual machine on an ESXi 6.7 host.
The DNS server required some more storage, so I expanded it on VMWare.

It was time to resize the LVM inside the virtual machine.

As I was performing the step of deleting the 2nd partition of the drive, to re-create it with the new size, I got prompted that the partition already contains an LVM signature and if I want to delete it.
Stupid as I am, I said yes and then written the changes to the partition table.

I quickly realized, that I just deleted something that the active system actually needs for LVM to function, and now it doesn't recognize the LVM anymore.

At this point, I created a snapshot in VMWare. I know it was stupid to not have created this earlier.

Generally said, I can back up all data and recreate the machine from that snapshot.

However, I'd like to know if it's possible to fix this mistake of mine on the running system, given that I have the following information from `/etc/lvm/backup/zeus-vg`:

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.03.07(2) (2019-11-30): Tue Nov  7 14:26:04 2023

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *after* executing 'pvresize /dev/sda2'"

creation_host = "zeus"  # Linux zeus 5.4.0-146-generic #163-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 17 18:26:02 UTC 2023 x86_64
creation_time = 1699363564      # Tue Nov  7 14:26:04 2023

zeus-vg {
        id = "QgSYzW-No1X-88Xm-Bs5J-wK2w-1oGo-Z4UxQH"
        seqno = 7
        format = "lvm2"                 # informational
        status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
        flags = []
        extent_size = 8192              # 4 Megabytes
        max_lv = 0
        max_pv = 0
        metadata_copies = 0

        physical_volumes {

                pv0 {
                        id = "rAgPpU-iVJg-3wFs-j4Br-0usv-3lew-HTsisM"
                        device = "/dev/sda2"    # Hint only

                        status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
                        flags = []
                        dev_size = 49276928     # 23.4971 Gigabytes
                        pe_start = 2048
                        pe_count = 6015 # 23.4961 Gigabytes
                }
        }

        logical_volumes {

                root {
                        id = "G8SCiJ-EiuE-42R7-vC84-2fb4-Jjbw-oOVhHm"
                        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                        flags = []
                        creation_time = 1626286622      # 2021-07-14 20:17:02 +0200
                        creation_host = "zeus"
                        segment_count = 1

                        segment1 {
                                start_extent = 0
                                extent_count = 5770     # 22.5391 Gigabytes

                                type = "striped"
                                stripe_count = 1        # linear

                                stripes = [
                                        "pv0", 0
                                ]
                        }
                }

                swap_1 {
                        id = "3FAmWU-ep0v-yfDH-2D9I-2RFc-W85E-8WR1jU"
                        status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
                        flags = []
                        creation_time = 1626286622      # 2021-07-14 20:17:02 +0200
                        creation_host = "zeus"
                        segment_count = 1

                        segment1 {
                                start_extent = 0
                                extent_count = 245      # 980 Megabytes

                                type = "striped"
                                stripe_count = 1        # linear

                                stripes = [
                                        "pv0", 5770
                                ]
                        }
                }
        }

}
```

I would like to know what to do in this case for training purposes, since it might as well have happened on a system that isn't running as a virtual machine.

This system is running Ubuntu 20.04 and here is the current state of that snapshot:

```
root@zeus:~# blkid
/dev/mapper/zeus--vg-swap_1: UUID="fef217b3-95dd-49ad-8cd5-d8868c34b5a5" TYPE="swap"
/dev/mapper/zeus--vg-root: UUID="5da6e8af-648b-4858-9391-a33e762c78a4" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2020-07-03-15-13-37-00" LABEL="Zentyal 6.2-development amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="3b07df6a" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: UUID="A21E-6989" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="7f5c8fe2-820d-4759-b500-b870a9a87842"
/dev/sda2: UUID="rAgPpU-iVJg-3wFs-j4Br-0usv-3lew-HTsisM" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="946b1bc7-09de-a544-ade1-c6bac5f765fb"
root@zeus:~# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 64 GiB, 68719476736 bytes, 134217728 sectors
Disk model: Virtual disk
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D04782E5-7205-40CA-AEB5-E96AAA334C9C

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 134217694 133167071 63.5G Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/zeus--vg-root: 22.55 GiB, 24201134080 bytes, 47267840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/zeus--vg-swap_1: 980 MiB, 1027604480 bytes, 2007040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
root@zeus:~# vgdisplay // doesn't return anything
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a backup of the LVM metadata, I can use that to restore the volume.

It required booting into a new live rescue environment and creating the backup file there.

Due to the partition table change and the removal of the LVM signature, the UUID of the disk changed.

Therefor I need to remove LVM metadata, using `pvremove /dev/sda2`

After that, I can recreate the physical volume with the original UUID:
`pvcreate --uuid "rAgPpU-iVJg-3wFs-j4Br-0usv-3lew-HTsisM" --restorefile lvm-restore-file /dev/sda2`

Since the volume is now recreated, I can restore the LVM metadata, using the backup file again:
`vgcfgrestore -f lvm-restore-file zeus-vg`

If that restoration is successful, I can run `vgchange -ay zeus-vg` to re-activate the volume group in the rescue environment.

The LVM should now be mountable:
`mount /dev/zeus-vg/root /mnt`

Having restored the LVM metadata, I can now perform the steps, that I previously couldn't do after my partition fuckup, which is to resize the LVM:

1. Resize physical volume `pvresize /dev/sda2`
2. Extend logical volume `lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/zeus-vg/root`
3. Resize the filesystem `resize2fs /dev/zeus-vg/root` (since I have an ext4 filesystem)

That was quite the journey.